# Getting Invalid Access Token error after authorizing via omniauth-linkedin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api, omniauth

Getting Following error when calling profile API

```
{
 errorCode: 0
 message: "Invalid access token."
 requestId: "7PQ0XX5WYL"
 status: 401
 timestamp: 1418976605501
}
```

When queried after authorizing user and obtaining access_token via https://github.com/skorks/omniauth-linkedin

My query looks like

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?oauth2_access_token=8d8bb5ad-XXX-9026cde508b6-XXX
```

Also Tried with passing token in header as mentioned at https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication, Step 4. Make an authenticated request

as

GET https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~

```
Connection: Keep-Alive
Authorization: Bearer 8d8bb5ad-XXX-9026cde508b6-XXX
Host: api.linkedin.com
x-li-format: json
```

My Response header looks like

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)        Chrome/38.0.2125.101 Safari/537.36
Authorization: Bearer 8d8bb5ad-XXX-9026cde508b6-XXX
x-li-format: json
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
```

I also referred this issue on linkedin developers site https://developer.linkedin.com/forum/invalid-access-token, but no updates (incomplete thread)

Am I doing something wrong, Any thoughts?

Comment: Am also getting the same error, did you find any fixes ?

Comment: @Dibish I was using OAuth 1.0 for auth flow, when I authenticated user through OAuth 2.0 with https://github.com/decioferreira/omniauth-linkedin-oauth2 gem, I got new token when I used new token error got resolved.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases this error message may be due to the fact that a more recent access token has been provisioned for the authenticated user which invalidates the access token you were mentioning in your question. If you were to take the user through the OAuth 2.0 flow again and try making an authenticated call using the new access token, do you still receive the same error?

Comment: I also tried re-authorizing user through OAuth 2.0 flow again, I got same access token and same error again, this access token have the 2 months of lifetime, so on every re-authorize getting same token for authorizing user

Comment: Resolved: I was using OAuth 1.0 for auth flow, when I authenticated user through OAuth 2.0 with github.com/decioferreira/omniauth-linkedin-oauth2 gem, I got new token when I used new token error got resolved